# How do I make a regex not 'swallow' a character?

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file like so

```
{word} definition
{another word} another definition {word} they don't have to be on different lines
```

The regex I was using was

```
    $regex = '/\{([a-z]+?)\}(.+?)\{/i';
```

This however, causes problems in that it *swallows* the last brace {, and then it won't match the next { in the next word.

To demonstrate, I did this for debugging purposes

```
echo preg_replace($regex, '<b style="background-color: red;">$1</b><b style="background-color: yellow;">$2</b>', $content);
```

Here is an example of my output (notice the opening brace in the next word isn't there, therefore it is not matched in the regex)

```
<b style="background-color: red;">shrub</b><b style="background-color: yellow;"> Multi stemmed woody plant</b>Abaxial}    side or face away from the axis
```

How can I amend my regex to get this to work? Thank you

**EDIT**

Many thanks for your answers. I've changed my regex like so

```
$regex = '/\{([a-z\-\s]+?)\}([^\{]+)/i';
```

I'll also look into the lookahead articles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this specific case, you could do:

```
$regex = '/\{([a-z]+?)\}([^\{]+)/i';
```

`[^\{]` means "match any character that is not a left brace".  This also has the advantage of not requiring a `{` at the end of your input.

More generally, you can also use lookahead assertions as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the [Look Ahead](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#10) feature to find a character, without capturing it.

You could restructure your regex as so.

```
$regex = '/\{([a-z]+?)\}(.+?)(?={)';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change the last part to match only non-curly brace characters instead of `.+` followed by a curly brace, like so:

```
$regex = '/\{([a-z]+?)\}([^{]+)/i';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).